# DDD modeling for a User Voice-like system

Tags: c#, ddd

I've taken on the challenge of modeling a simple User Voice-like system. High-level description:

- It's a portal for some SaaS users;
- They come and leave feature requests, suggestions, etc.;
- They should be able to vote/unvote for any suggestions;
- They can leave as many comments as they like on suggestions;
- Comments may be removed by the owner, but may not be edited.

I've modeled the domain as follows, using a DDD approach. Please advise about mistakes, warnings, improvements, etc.

I've also applied the advices from these posts:

- [Don't create aggregate roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)
- [Creating new aggregates in DDD](https://gedgei.wordpress.com/2016/10/19/creating-new-aggregates-in-ddd/)
- [Link to an aggregate: reference or Id?](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/03/08/link-to-an-aggregate-reference-or-id/)

```cs
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class User : Entity // Aggregate Root
{
    public string Key => $"{Email}:{MarketplaceUrl}";

    public string Name { get; }

    public string Email { get; }

    public string MarketplaceName { get; }

    public Uri MarketplaceUrl { get; }

    internal User(string name, string email, string marketplaceName, Uri marketplaceUrl)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        MarketplaceName = marketplaceName;
        MarketplaceUrl = marketplaceUrl;
    }

    public Suggestion MakeSuggestion(string text)
    {
        return new Suggestion(this, text);
    }
}

public class Suggestion : Entity // Aggregate Root
{
    public string Text { get; /* a suggestion cannot be altered */ }

    public User ByUser { get; }

    public DateTime SuggestedAt { get; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; } = new List<Comment>();

    public ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; } = new List<Vote>();

    internal Suggestion(User byUser, string text)
    {
        ByUser = byUser;
        Text = text;
        SuggestedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public Comment AddComment(User byUser, string text)
    {
        var comment = new Comment(byUser, text);
        Comments.Add(comment);
        return comment;
    }

    public void RemoveComment(Comment comment, User userRemovingComment)
    {
        Comments.Remove(comment);
    }

    public void Unvote(User byUser)
    {
        var vote = Votes.SingleOrDefault(v => v.ByUser == byUser));

        if (vote != null)
            Votes.Remove(vote);
    }

    public Vote Vote(User byUser)
    {
        if (Votes.Any(v => v.ByUser == byUser))
            throw new CannotVoteTwiceOnSameSuggestionException();

        var vote = new Vote(byUser);
        Votes.Add(vote);
        return vote;
    }
}

public class Comment : Entity
{
    public string Text { get; /* a comment cannot be changed */ }

    public User ByUser { get; }

    public DateTime CommentedAt { get; }

    internal Comment(User byUser, string text)
    {
        ByUser = byUser;
        Text = text;
        CommentedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public class Vote : Entity
{
    public User ByUser { get; }

    public DateTime VotedAt { get; }

    internal Vote(User byUser)
    {
        ByUser = byUser;
        VotedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public interface IUserVoiceStore
{
    Task AddUserAsync(User user);

    Task AddSuggestionAsync(Suggestion suggestion);

    Task<Suggestion> GetSuggestionAsync(Guid id);

    Task<User> GetUserAsync(Guid id);

    // For when comments and votes are added/removed to/from a suggestion.
    Task UpdateSuggestionAsync(Suggestion suggestion);
}

public class UserVoiceService
{
    private readonly IUserVoiceStore store;

    public UserVoiceService(IUserVoiceStore store)
    {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public async Task<User> RegisterUserAsync(string name, string email, string marketplaceName, Uri marketplaceUrl)
    {
        var user = new User(name, email, marketplaceName, marketplaceUrl);
        await store.AddUserAsync(user);
        return user;
    }
}

public class CannotVoteTwiceOnSameSuggestionException : Exception { }

public class CannotRemoveCommentFromAnotherUserExcetion : Exception { }
```

Comment: You are not using the `CannotRemoveComment...Exception` anywhere?

Comment: @t3chb0t my mistake; I edited the code at Suggestion.RemoveComment to validate the user and throw if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast sorry about that. I'll revert the code to its original form and then post a link to a Gist with the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design looks solid, a few thoughts though:

- I would split `IUserVoiceStore` into more granular `UserRepository` and `SuggestionRepository`. Also, `UpdateSuggestionAsync()` seems to indicate you can only update a suggestion and nothing else at a time, which can be limiting. It also IMO goes out of a repository's jurisdiction to flush a specific object to persistent storage. Using some kind of separate unit of work class where you can put multiple objects to be updated as part of a business transaction might be a better idea.
- Not always feasible, but maybe change the type of link between `Suggestion` and `User` from a full reference to just an ID to avoid the temptation of manipulating 2 aggregate roots at the same time. *(I don't agree with the article you linked to in that regard)*
- Keep an eye on suggestions with a large number of comments - depending on concurrent access, they can clog up your system and cause locking problems, especially if comments become more sophisticated, with images and so on.

Comment: So split the repo by Aggregate Root; nice, code updated. About your 3rd suggestion, do you think I should promote Comment to an AR and have a dedicated Repo? It does make some sense.

Comment: Also, about your 2nd suggestion, it is according to Vernon's advice, see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=4 - Rule: Reference Other Aggregates by Identity. I'll update the code accordingly

Comment: About promoting Comment, it would be premature optimization to do it without some transactional analysis based on real or expected numbers.